# Cannot Query with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, flickr

I am using Retrofit and I want to query FlickR based on a search term that a user enters. I want to make sure I have it set up correctly, as I have limited experiences with Retrofit/REST. Any tutorials, advice, and commentary on my code would be appreciated.

I have labeled some of the items "UNSURE" where I didn't know what exactly was supposed to be entered. With REST, is "q" always used to denote a query?

At the end of the day, I want the image results to be displayed in a GridView and available for selection to the user:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchTerm;
private Button mRequestButton;
private String mQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText_search_term);
    mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_button);
    mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mQuery = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<Photo>> call = apiInterface.getPhotos(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });



}

//Synchronous vs. Asynchronous
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=<mQuery>&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json")  //
    Call<List<Photo>> getPhotos(@Query("q") String photoSearchTerm);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.  BTW looks like you're using Retrofit 1.9; Retrofit 2 is available and you may want to switch now as eventually I assume 1.9 will be deprecated.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://api.flickr.com/services")
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)//log your request
        .build();
 }

public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/rest")  //
void getPhotos(@Query("method") String method, @Query("api_key") String key, @Query ("user_id") String user, @Query("format") String format, @Query("city") String city, Callback<FlickrResponse> callback);
     }
```

`FlickrResponse` is a Java class that represents the response you're expecting.  You can plug some example JSON into this and then tweak the result as needed: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.  There could be some other details that aren't exactly right but that should get you started.  You can research request interceptors if you would like to avoid passing the key and user id and such every time.  That way you can define an interceptor that will inject them into the request and you can remove those parameters from the interface.

Here's some info on migrating to Retrofit 2: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will be experimenting with it, however I noticed that you removed the photo search portion of my query. I was basing it off of this documentation: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Comment: I recommend you to learn a little more about http/REST. Everything that goes after "?" are query parameters. nasch transformed the method=flickr.photos.search to a method parameter. So you would need to call getPhotos("flickt.photos.search") to have the same method value. The other are the next fields in the search. I recommend you to test it using a http client to understand what is going on, like postman (browser plugin) or curl.

Comment: Much appreciated, do you have any recommendations on http/REST tutorials? I have read a bit on it but a comprehensive tutorial would be beneficial.

Comment: I am going to get going on this a bit more and was hoping you knew of some documentation / tutorial to help me better understand how to query FlickR with Retrofit.

Comment: Are you looking to understand the Flickr API, or Retrofit, or both?  And are you sticking with Retrofit 1.9 or moving to 2?

Comment: I would guess it makes more sense to learn 2.0. With Retrofit, my understanding is all API calls are similar, thus a basic understanding of Retrofit would be useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK have you looked for retrofit tutorials?

Comment: Yes, having some difficulty mapping the JSON that I receive from FlickR. I added a JSON extension to my chrome browser but that does not seem to be helping at this point

Comment: I have updated my code and read up on Retrofit 2.0. Based on my code and my logcat, it looks like I am querying the API correctly. However, I am a bit confused with how to map the JSON response from FlickR with my POJO/Java model object.

Comment: Post the json and your pojo.

Comment: I have updated the code again. I am using the FlickR photos.search method and am having trouble figuring out where I enter the search query entered by the user in an EditText.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Flickr API. This sounds like it might be a separate question.